# How can I update multiple mysql columns of a row using the result of a select query?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a reviews table that contains three ways to rate an item. The items themselves then have three columns to hold the average for each value respectively.

I could do this using three nested queries in an update query, but I feel like this is inefficient... Is there a way to update them all at once?

So far I've used this as my select query:

```
SELECT AVG(rating_1),AVG(rating_2),AVG(rating_3) FROM items_reviews WHERE item_id = 1
```

I just don't know how to use the result of that query to update an item row.

Comment: I think a query using 3 sub-queries is the best solution here. The performance impact is probably negligible.

Comment: Heh, thanks for your efforts! I did try both your solutions, but I had no luck. Probably my naivety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an join in the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE items a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        item_id,
        AVG(rating_1) AS avg1, 
        AVG(rating_2) AS avg2, 
        AVG(rating_3) AS avg3
    FROM items_reviews
    WHERE item_id = 1
    GROUP BY item_id
) b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
SET 
    a.avgrating1 = b.avg1,
    a.avgrating2 = b.avg2,
    a.avgrating3 = b.avg3
```

Comment: That's one impressive query, at first I thought it was updating all items. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, I suppose that particular one does, heh.

Comment: In this case yes. I think there will be far fewer reviews than updates say on an interval.

Comment: @Bob, see my edit, you just need to add the `WHERE item_id = 1` in the subselect to update a specific item.